# Scraping nested tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I know this type of question comes up frequently, however I have been browsing and have not seen a similar problem.

```
<div class="casts">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="">
                    <a class="cast">
                        <span class="title">
                            Nested data 1 
                            <span class="schedule">
                                Nested data 2
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

There are multiple td's with the same structure, however I removed the rest just for simplicity.  Assuming I want to pull the data `Nested data 1` and `Nested data 2` from the spans I was using the following:

```
finda = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class':'cast'})

for var in finda:
  var2 = var.find_all('span')
```

Using:

`var2[1]`

im able to pull all of the `Nested data 2`

But I am unable to pull only `Nested data 1`

`var2[0]`

will return `Nested data2 Nested data1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished in a more or less simple way by iterating through the children of each of the spans:

**stack.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>StackO</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="casts">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="">
            <a class="cast">
              <span class="title">
                Nested data 1 
                <span class="schedule">
                  Nested data 2
                  <span class="moar-nesting">
                    Nested data 3
                  </span>
                </span>
                Nested data 4
              </span>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**meanwhile, over in ipython land....**

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Comment

In [2]: with open('stack.html', 'r') as f:
   ...:     markup = f.read()
   ...:

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(markup)

In [4]: casts = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'cast'})

In [5]: cast = casts[0]

In [6]: for span in cast.find_all('span'):
   ...:     for child in span.children:
   ...:         if isinstance(child, NavigableString) and not isinstance(child, Comment) and str(child).strip() != "":
   ...:             print '"{}"'.format(str(child).strip())
   ...:
"Nested data 1"
"Nested data 4"
"Nested data 2"
"Nested data 3"

In [10]:
```